Obtaining a Vec<X> from a &HashSet<X>
Assume I have some function do_stuff that takes a &HashSet<X> and wants to collect the items into a Vec<X> by copying all the elements. What is the canonical way to do that? I have basically found the following ways to do this:

Using _.clone().into_iter().collect() (GodBolt Link):
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct X {}

struct Y {
    xs: HashSet<X>,
}

fn do_stuff(y: &Y) -> Vec<X> {
    y.xs.clone().into_iter().collect()
}

This is recommended here:

How can I collect Vec from &HashSet? - Answer by at54321


Using _.iter().cloned().collect() (GodBolt Link):
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct X {}

struct Y {
    xs: HashSet<X>,
}

fn do_stuff(y: &Y) -> Vec<X> {
    y.xs.iter().cloned().collect()
}

This is recommended here:

Build HashSet from a vector in Rust - Answer by Fuji
How can I collect Vec from &HashSet? - Comment by Masklinn
Is there a built in function to compute the difference of two sets? - Answer by Paul
HashSet from Vec while maintaining the order of elements - Answer by connicpu
What is the idiomatic way of converting a Vec of references to a Vec of values? - Answer by hellow


Using Vec::from_iter(_.iter().cloned()) (GodBolt Link):
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct X {}

struct Y {
    xs: HashSet<X>,
}

fn do_stuff(y: &Y) -> Vec<X> {
    Vec::from_iter(y.xs.iter().cloned())
}

This is recommended here:

Build HashSet from a vector in Rust - Answer by bluss
Collecting from HashSet to Vector - Answer by notriddle
HashSet from Vec while maintaining the order of elements - Question by StackLeak



I have two questions:

What is the essential difference between the above methods?

What is the canonical way to collect the items from a &HashSet<X> into a Vec<X>?


Related:

How to determine whether to use .clone() and .cloned() with iterators - Answer by Chayim Friedman


https://xkcd.com/927/

This question is not opinion-based at all. It is simply asking which of the options is idiomatic and which is idiosyncratic. I cannot understand the close reason.

What is the objective definition of "idiomatic"? Your idiomatic might be my idiosyncratic and vice versa. It's inherently subjective. Additionally the one answer you got ends with IMO which when written out is "in my opinion" so how can you argue it is not opinion based?


_.clone().into_iter().collect()

This one creates an intermediate copy of HashSet. Which is not something you want, its an unneeded allocation and processing. The rule of thumb is: prefer .cloned() over .clone().
These two:

_.iter().cloned().collect()
Vec::from_iter(_.iter().cloned())

are equivalent. The first one is more readable IMO.
